# Creating rolling aggregate values in data frames Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

I am currently working with financial data and I am stuck on the last step of my analysis. I have a large panel data with many different companies and their returns throughout the the years, and the values across the years for the same company are not ordered. Similar to something like this:

```
        year     ticker     return_y
0       1985      VLID       -0.5838
1       1985        KO        0.3245
2       1994       CTL       -0.3063
3       1996      DRYR       -0.1607
..       ...       ...           ...
1356    2002      CHUX       -0.2456
1357    1987       HRL       -0.0233
1358    2015        KO        0.2343
..       ...       ...           ...
56798   2017      AFMXF       0.0558
56799   2014        TER       0.0134
```

What I have been trying to do is to create a separate data frame which sums the returns for each company on a 3 year rolling basis, and that if a year is missing (e.g. we have 1999 and 2001 but not 2000) restarts the rolling from the next point. Therefore something like this:

```
        3_years      ticker     return_y
0       1985-1987      VLID      -0.0245
1       1986-1988      VLID       0.0366
2       1987-1989      VLID      -0.0421
3       1993-1995      VLID      -0.1607
..       ...            ...          ...
12569   2008-2010     AFMXF       0.2349
12570   2012-2015     AFMXF       0.1112
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We need a better sample dataset. Your current sample dataset cannot produce your expected output.

Comment: df.sort_value('year').groupby('ticker').rolling(3).mean()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data frame is called `df`.

**In short:**

You would do something like that:

```
# ts stands for time on y-axis and security on x-axys
returns_ts = df.pivot(index='year', columns='ticker', values='return_y')
rolling_returns_ts = returns_ts.rolling(3).sum()
```

This will give you the rolling returns in a different format (one I find easier to work with).

To get them back to the format you have described you can:

```
old_format_rolling_returns = rolling_returns_ts.stack().reset_index()
```

Note that this assumes that the `years` axis needs to be a `datetime` format.
Also note that for the conversion you want, then you need to change `years` format again to the one you like.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the explanation - I just has a slight question tho, is this method able to understand when a year is skipped (e.g. is missing from the df)?

Comment: So this will simply do a rolling of 3 periods over the dates. It will not understand if a year is skipped.
Can you please explain what do you mean by this, so I can understand better?

Comment: So in this case there is the risk that during the rolling period we are missing a year of returns, let's say that for company X we have years: 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005. 
In this case we cannot make a roll over for the years 2001-2003, because 2002 is missing, but we must have 2 separate rolls: 1999-2001 and 2003-2005.
Is it clearer now? :)

Comment: Sure, so it depends what you want to achieve. If you want compute 3 year mean with one year missing (effectively 2 year mean), then you have to insert these years for each instrument with nan (the way I change the DF this is quite easy to do).
Or if you want to always have 3 year rolling mean (so if 2001 is missing then it will do 2000, 2002, 2003), then the code above works fine.

Comment: So I actually want to keep the aggregated values, and not do the mean - that's why its important for me that if a year is missing then the count starts again (but i don't know if its possible, just wondering ahah). But thank you for your quick replies!

Comment: It's possible. A mean is an aggregated value though.
So I am a bit confused still what you are aiming to achieve? What's the single value created form the returns over 3 years?

Comment: In my real df my values are not returns but abnormal returns, but I didn't want everyone waste time trying to understand what they are :P So abnormal returns are the difference between the realized return and that of a benchmark - so its a return that, let's say, is unexplained.

Comment: This doesn't matter. It's a float from a programming perspective. : ) Anyway, I hope this helps get you started.